# SQL Server multiple condition constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, check-constraints

I have a SQL table like this.

```
create table test
(
id int not null,
var1 varchar(20) not null,
var1_a int null,
var1_b date null,
var1_c varchar(50) null,
var2 varchar(20) null,
var2_a int null,
var2_b date null,
var2_c varchar(50) null,
var3 varchar(20) null,
var3_a int null,
var3_b date null,
var3_c varchar(50) null
);
```

I want to create check constraints that do the following

1. If var2 is populated then var1 should be populated. If var3 is populated then var2 and var1 should be populated.
2. If atleast one of (var2_a or var2_b or var2_c) are populated then var2 should be populated.
3. If var2 is populated then atleast one of (var2_a or var2_b or var2_c) should be populated

Comment: I would create computed column that makes all the logic, and results with 'true' / 'false'. then make the check constraint = 'true'

Comment: Why would we need both a computer column as well as a check constraint for this scenario. Isn't it double the effort. Do you have an example implementation where 1 computed column has multiple checks on the table data. (e.g:  computed column containing comma separated list of Check#1, Check#2....etc. The requirement is to prevent bad data insert (as per user requirement), if a condition was satisfied. If there are >3 check constraints required on the same table, is there a better way to handle this.